# Extract portion of string startswith 4 digit number and ends with period

Tags: r, regex

I have a character vector like the following:

```
char <- c("cancer_6_53_7575_tumor.csv", "control_7_4_7363_healthy.csv")
```

I want to extract the portion of the string starting with the "7" in the 4 digit patient ID and ending with the ".", but the following method doesn't work when there is a 7 before that patient ID.

```
values <- unlist(qdapRegex::rm_between(char, "7", ".", extract = TRUE))
```

How do I specify that it must start with the 7 in the 4 digit number?

Comment: The question is how you can identify the patient ID part. The answers below are based on different assumptions. What if there is `cancer_6_57383_7575_tumor.draft.csv`? Or `cancer_6_7383_7575_tumor.draft.csv`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this:

```
char <- c("cancer_6_53_7575_tumor.csv", "control_7_4_7363_healthy.csv")
gsub(".*(7\\d{3}.*)\\..*$", "\\1", char)
[1] "7575_tumor" "7363_healthy"
```

1. It searches for a 3 digit string after 7 (makes it 4 digit string): `7\\d{3}`
2. And starts to record pattern till first `.` : `(7\\d{3}.*)\\.`
3. Then it prints recorded pattern: `\\1`

Comment: @JackArnestad Is there any way I can improve my solution so you would accept it?

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use `stringr`.

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(char, '7\\d{3}[^\\.]*')
## [1] "7575_tumor"   "7363_healthy"
```

It will match 4 numbers starting with `7` and everything until the dot - `.`.